# mvc 4 razor engine Authorization using Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I am using MVC 4 Razor engine and selected the project template as Intranet. So it uses Windows Authentication. Currently I have designed a Database with Tables to maintain the users and the role that they belong to. I would like to show specific screens alone to specific users bases on the roles.

For Example: Add User, Create Role Screens to Admins alone. And the rest of the screens to Users of Non Admin Role & Admin Role.

Basically, I would like to Authorize the users based on the Roles as per the Database Table. How can I achieve this? Please let me know if there are any articles for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not have access to Use the Active Directory to Authenticate User. Hence, I have Used Windows Authentication so that I can fetch the details of the User Logged into Windows Machine (User.Identity.Name). I have a table in SQL Database where in this user name is mapped to a specific Role. For Authorization I would like to check against this UserName & Role and allow the users to access a particular page.

Answer (score 1):

You talk in the title about Windows Authentication, which implies an Active Directory, and then you say you want to authenticate users against a database (forms authentication), please, correct your question.

Here is a full tutorial about forms authentication in mvc 4

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I do not have access to Use the Active Directory to Authenticate User. Hence, I have Used Windows Authentication so that I can fetch the details of the User Logged into Windows Machine (User.Identity.Name). I have a table in SQL Database where in this user name is mapped to a specific Role. For Authorization I would like to check against this UserName & Role and allow the users to access a particular page.

Comment: If I use Forms Authentication, will I be able to access the Windows Logged In User (User.Identity.Name)?

Comment: Whenever you use forms, windows or basic authentication the Identity is always set after success authentication. However, I think you are missing concepts. You can not use Windows authentication without an Active Directory.

Comment: Yes, I am not completely sure of the concepts. But when I set the application to Windows Authentication in IIS, it prompts me to enter the Windows Credentials and actually validates it. By that I mean, if i provide a wrong Password for the user name, it does not show up the page and says HTTP error code 403. So might be, that is inturn validating against the Active Directory but I have not written any piece of code to validate against AD... Do you mean to say that, I can use the it to Authorize against the Database by still setting the Authentication as Windows in IIS?